# Restarting dependency docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

as per this docker-compose file

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  b:
    image: b
    restart: "on-failure"
    ports:
      - "6002:6002"
  a:
    image: a
    restart: "on-failure"
    depends_on:
      - b
  c:
    image: c
    restart: "on-failure"
```

in case container `a` restarts container `b` should be restarted.

Any guidance please help.

I tried placing the shell script in dockerfile container.
Since I can't come docker-compose directory this attempt failed.

Comment: Easy way: Just make your `b` process crash out if `a` crashes.

Comment: What's the code in `b` that can't tolerate a restart of `a`; could that be fixed?

Comment: I've a variation on this: I've a proxy in front of a service... and if the service is restarted (say with an updated image), the proxy loses connections. A simple restart fixes it.... but that restart is an extra command in the deploy script.